# insert different block in the middle of block content

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml, static-block

I have a phtml for a block like this :

**app/code/Vendor/Modul/view/frontend/templates/main.phtml**

```
<div class="business-container">
  <nav class="mini-head">
  </nav>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="right-section">
    </div>
    <div class="left-section"> 
       <!-- Dynamic phtml Content  -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to use above phtml in 2 different pages, but for the `left-section` div class it will have different phtml content , is it possible to do this?

Comment: As you are on `phtml`, you can use `if-else` condition